# Batch import a folder structure of PDFs into Onenote

Tags: batch, microsoft-onenote, import

I have a folder structure containing PDFs that I'd like to import into OneNote. I'm aware of hacks that let me import a bunch of PDFs at a time, but they all go into the same notebook/section. Are there any ways to preserve the folder structure going into OneNote, so that top-level folders map to sections, next level to pages, next level to sub pages (or similar)?